# Graphing API Hits Per Minute

Tags: metrics, graphite

I am trying to graph the number of times an API is called per minute. 
Using Coda Hale metrics with Graphite I can see a continuous count (ie if the API is called 5 times it will show a constant line across time for the value 5) alternatively I can see the exponentially weighted moving average per minute.............  But all I want to see is the number of times the API is called per minute. I have tried using Coda Hale's counters, timers and meters and have also tried using the Graphite render functions, but cannot get what I want.

Has anybody done this before - Apologies if this is a basic question

Answer (score 7):

You should first derive your counter to get a graph representing the changes e.g. *hits* and then summarize per minute: `"summarize(nonNegativeDerivative(my.metric.counter),'1minute')"`.

EDIT: Since `smartSummarize` is experimental I changed the line above.

Comment: Actually - smartSummarize wouldn't work for me but summarize did the trick.......Thanks Very Much

Comment: Ok I've added a hint to the original answer.